# Trying to connect my app to Neon DB and it gives me authentication error even setting everything right

Tags: database, postgresql, backend, serverless, drizzle

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCmQD.png)

I am trying to connect my app to Neon DB with .env key DATABASE_URL and it gives me password authentication error and when created another account it gives me no such a user.
Please if you can help me with a solution

Comment: 1.What did you do to get the error, were you connecting the app from the command line? 2.Provide more information: the code snippet where .env key DATABASE_URL is and the commands you used?

Comment: 1. yes, i am connecting from VS Code terminal 2. The same key NeonDB gave me

Comment: From the connection details dashboard of Neon db, change your password and download the new .env file. Make sure your code / file reflects the new connection details. Just make sure there is no mismatch of details.